# How do I match something that is not a letter or a number or a space?

Tags: ruby, regex, space, alphanumeric

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I match something that is not a letter or a number or a space?  I tried

```
2.4.0 :004 > str = "-"
 => "-"
2.4.0 :005 > str =~ /[^[:alnum:]]*/
 => 0
2.4.0 :006 > str = " "
 => " "
2.4.0 :007 > str =~ /[^[:alnum:]]*/
 => 0
```

but as you can see it is still matching a space.

Comment: `[^[:alnum:]]` matches any non-alphanum char. Try `[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+` to match any char other than alphanum/whitespace chars.

Comment: Seriously, lose the irb-prompts. They distract from the actual code and force someone trying to help you, to edit after copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/[^[:alnum:]]*/` pattern matches 0 or more symbols other than alphanumeric chars. It will match whitespace.

To match 1 or more chars other than alphanumeric and whitespace, you can use

```
/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+/
```

Use the negated bracket expression with the relevant POSIX character classes inside.